# Android dialog fragment not dismissing

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have created one dialog fragment in app. Following is the code for it.

```
public class AlertLoader extends DialogFragment {

Typeface fontRegular;


Bundle bundle;

String displayText = "";

public static AlertLoader newInstance(@NonNull String displayText) {
    AlertLoader alertPopUpMenu = new AlertLoader();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("displayText", displayText);
    alertPopUpMenu.setArguments(args);

    return alertPopUpMenu;
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null && dialog.getWindow() != null) {
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bundle = getArguments();
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.LoaderDialogTheme);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_loader, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    init(view);
}

private void init(View mainView) {
    displayText = bundle.getString("displayText");

    TextView mLoadingText = (TextView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.loadertext);
    mLoadingText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    mLoadingText.setTypeface(fontRegular);

    if (displayText == null || displayText.length() == 0) {
        mLoadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        mLoadingText.setText(displayText);
        mLoadingText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void dismissCurrentView() {
    getDialog().dismiss();

}

}
```

I am using following code to show dialog.

```
 private void showLoader(String displayText) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    AlertLoader newFragment = AlertLoader.newInstance(displayText);
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

It is working fine. I am trying to dismiss it by following code.

```
    private void dismissLoader() {
    Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        DialogFragment df = (DialogFragment) prev;
        df.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I am dismissing my loader before navigating to next activity. Following is my code where i am dismissing loader.

```
   dismissLoader();
   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ShareMediaActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra(UserDefault.bundlePath, file.getAbsolutePath());
   startActivity(intent);
```

But when i come back to previous activity , dialog still displays. This code for showing and dismissing is working fine in other cases.

I have tried several ways to dismiss it but not working. Anyone could help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: does your code ever fall under this line ((prev != null)) ?

Comment: cast `prev` in `AlertLoader`  then try...

Comment: @k0sh yes it does.

Comment: @ ak sacha Let me try

Answer (score 2):

Create a field for `DialogFragment` as below

```
private AlertLoader newFragment;

private void showLoader(String displayText) {
  FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
  if (prev != null) {
      ft.remove(prev);
  }
  ft.addToBackStack(null);

  newFragment = AlertLoader.newInstance(displayText);
  newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

Then use that field to dismiss the `DialogFragment`

```
private void dismissLoader() {
  if (newFragment != null) {
      newFragment.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: from where are you calling the `showLoader()` method